# Generating a Python script from a mesh?

Tags: python, scripting

I've seen that somewhere here in BSE, but I am not able to find it again:

Is there a Python script (or addon or operator) which generates a script into a text block able to recreate a given mesh (I mean here with the wanted static data inside, not simply copying the mesh)?

I could do it myself, but if a script already exists, it could be much more complete than I am able to do (for instance having options, such as about UV map, object's rotation and scale, modifiers, materials, etc.).

Comment: Rigify-Addon has an operator in *Edit Mode* converting a mesh into raw data, if that's the question...?

Comment: Perhaps this q? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56993/how-can-i-export-my-blender-model-as-a-python-script