# How can I find Python structured faces and vertices of a blender object?

Tags: python, mesh, vertices, faces

I am new to Blender and would like som help to extract Blender mesh information, such as faces and vertices so I can use it in my Python project. I have found a video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gVUvnSJ-t3M) showing how to create objects in blender from Python code, and this is also the mesh structure I would like to use, e.g.

```
verts = [(0,0,0), (0,5,0), (5,5,0), (5,0,0), (0,0,5), (0,5,5), (5,5,5), (5,0,5)]
faces = [(0,1,2,3), (7,6,5,4), (0,4,5,1), (1,5,6,2), (2,6,7,3), (3,7,4,0)]
```

However, I would like to do it the other way around. First create a 3D object in blender, and then extract the mesh information to Python.

Can you help me?

Comment: I found this topic to be the answer:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56993/how-can-i-export-my-blender-model-as-a-python-script